# Asp Menuhiding behind asp dropdown

Tags: html, asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

I have a master page which contains asp menu control which is dropping down values on hover,which is working fine.But my issue is if the page is having an asp:dropdown list control,the menu is hides behind the dropdownlist select.
what i tried is i put astyle to asp:menu 'DynamicMenuStyle' tag

```
  .DynamicMenu {
   z-index: 10000;
    }
```

also provide style to 'DynamicMenuItemStyle' tag

```
   .DynamicMenuItem {
    z-index:10000;
    }
   .DynamicMenuItem:hover {
    z-index:10000;
    }
    a.DynamicMenuItem:hover {
    z-index:10000;
    }
    a.DynamicMenuItem {
    z-index:10000;
    }
```

Still the issue is there...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding z-index to your asp:dropdown lesser than the DynamicMenu. I would suggest you to use the firebug add-on in firefox and try changing the z-index and other css attributes to fix. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

you see the menu because not load inner page.
after inner page loadeed upper side and your menu is back side.

1- you must back your menu to upper side. your css is work.

2- inner page set z-inex=0 and send it back side :)